# Spring framework Upgrade

Tags: linux, spring, upgrade

I test my system vulnerabilities where I was given solution to upgrade the spring framework version but the problem is that I didn't use any spring framework. I am using linux terminal  I also did a cross check whether I have accidentally installed spring framework or not using the command below:

```
sudo yum list --installed | more
```

I checked using the above command but there was no spring framework in the system. Please, can anyone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring framework is used to build web applications and its core features can be used by any Java based application. It is possible that you have some applications that use this in the background. (If I am understanding your question right)

But if you want to test vulnerabilities in Linux, there are different ways of doing it.
**Package audit tools**: you can use Gentoo: **glsa-check** or openSUSE: **zypper lp** (grep security) or Fedora / RHEL: **yum list-sec security** or Ubuntu: **apt-check** based on the platform you use.

**Linux security audit**: Tools line lynis and SCAP can be used to check flaws in system security and configurations.

There are some other Linux security tools available here: https://linuxsecurity.expert/security-tools/vulnerability-scanners

Best way to avoid any weakness in the system is to not install what you will not need. So, minimalistic installation can be used for that.